# using jquery on a div loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, load

I have a PHP page where I display in a Div values obtained from a database. This div is loading data automatically using Ajax. My problem is that when the Div is reloaded I can´t use Jquery functions or attributes overs objects in the Div (Like converting a label in button).

This is the code I´m using:
//jquery

```
 $(function() { 
            $("label").button();
    });
```

//ajax

```
var RequestObject = false;
var unidad = <?php echo json_encode($unidad);?>;
parametros='?unidad='+ unidad;

var Archivo = 'obtiene_ultimas_lecturas.php'+ parametros ;
window.setInterval("actualizacion_reloj()", 15000); 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)    
    RequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();  
 if (window.ActiveXObject)     
    RequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  

function ReqChange() {  
if (RequestObject.readyState==4) {  
    if (RequestObject.responseText.indexOf('invalid') == -1)   
    {   
    document.getElementById("marco").innerHTML = RequestObject.responseText;  
    }  
    else 
    {  
    document.getElementById("marco").innerHTML = "Error llamando";  
    }  
  }  
}         

function llamadaAjax() {  
        RequestObject.open("GET", Archivo , true);  
    RequestObject.onreadystatechange = ReqChange;  
    RequestObject.send(null);   
 }  

function actualizacion_reloj() {  
    llamadaAjax();  
  }
```

//html

```
 <div id="marco" name="marco">
    <table> 
     <tr class="Estilo4">
          <td align="center"><input name="nge" type="text" size="9" value="<?php printf("%.3f",$nge); ?>" />&nbsp;<label>m³</label></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

This is basically my code, I'd want to label contained in div could get 'button' attribute.

Comment: Call `$("label").button()` after the ajax completes

Comment: @user1082159 i suggest you to use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for ajax functionality

Comment: You can use `replaceWith` function of `jquery` http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ . Also call that function in `ReqChange`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it for you..

```
function actualizacion_reloj() {  
    llamadaAjax();  
    $("label").button();
  }
```